# How to affect multiple HTML elements in one command written in Pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, pure-js

I can add a CSS class to each element by iterating them, but is it possible to add the class to all of them at the same time?

*Example:*
Suppose I have 3 elements, when I add the class to 1st element the change would reflect the 1st element only and not the other two. I want it to wait until the same class has been added to other two elements too.

Right now I am doing this:

```
card1.classList.add('animated', 'rubberBand');
card2.classList.add('animated', 'rubberBand');
```

But animation for `card1` will happen as soon as it is added right? Or my understanding of the reflow is wrong?

Comment: Hello, please, read [ask] and also [mcve], then [edit] your question fo fulfill the stackOverflow requirements to your question be on-topic and focused

Comment: The browser doesn't re-render every time you add a class to an element. It will batch the updates up anyway. To add the same calss to multiple elements you will need to iterate through the collection anyway.

Comment: ohh, didnt know about the batches. but how long does it hold up ?

Comment: Browsers are very fast at iteration: unless you're adding a class to tens or hundreds of thousands of DOM elements, you shouldn't worry about that.

Comment: _“but is it possible to add the class to all of them at the same time?”_ - that is not even _necessary_, if you actually use CSS with a bit of “cleverness” … Add one single class to a common parent element, and use the descendant combinator in your stylesheet to create a rule that affects _all_ of your target elements based simply on that.